# What is the view of different dharma shastras on domestic violence against women?

Tags: dharma, women, dharma-shastras, manu-smriti

What do different dharma shastras say about domestic violence against women, is domestic violence treated as sin in majority of them? I would like to know from different dharma shastras especially the shastra by ved vyasa and parashar.

Comment: violence is violence...no matter what the context. Using the word 'domestic' does not make it any better or worse.

Comment: Since you try to justify domestic violence it might be okay to you

Comment: @RakeshJoshi its not, when did I justify domestic violence?

Comment: @AnubhavJha by quoting wife beating etc from brihadaranyak

Comment: @RakeshJoshi no, I was just showing you that brahmanams have such content too. You were looking down upon sanyas scriptures.

Comment: @AnubhavJha so you accept such verses or not ? Be clear...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I don't, Lord Krishna himself condemns brahmanams in geeta because of their elaborate rituals, I consider geeta and Brahma sutras as the last conclusion of Vedas and interpret Vedas according to them.

Comment: @AnubhavJha i dont accept that. Anyhow geeta brands women as papayoni too in 9.32

Comment: @RakeshJoshi no that verses has multiple interpretation, also that verses is not demeaning women but saying that anyone whatever be his/her social standing that takes refuge in Krishna can be saved, Lord Krishna is breaking the tradition which said that only sanyasins can get moksha, he says that whoever worships him comes to him, he also says that he is father and mother, saying that he is beyond the concept of human gender, he is mother too he loves everyone equally.

Comment: @AnubhavJha what tradition ? Do you know what are you talking? All rishis were grihasthas so there is no tradition that sanyasin only get moksha. In fact all rishis got moksha while being married...

Comment: @RakeshJoshi yes, I meant that Krishna is breaking tradition, when Lord Krishna was giving geeta, that status of women wasn't so good, he is being accommodating and saying that gender or social standing doesn't matter for getting moksha.

Comment: Sir, in this kali yuga, your question can become a stimulus for domestic violence. It's better to state very clear the opposition to domestic and any kind of violence. I recommend you to edit your question and make some citation about ahimsa and discourage violence

Comment: The part about treatment of women made your question too broad, so I edited it out.

Comment: By the way, Krishna does not condemn the Brahmanas of the Vedas, he condemns those who focus exclusively on the Brahmanas of the Vedas to the exclusion of the Jnana Kanda, i.e. Purva Mimamsa people.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan well still, to some extent he did.

Comment: No, he didn't condemn any part of the Vedas.  He just condemned people who took a wrong attitude to the Vedas.

Comment: As per a 1990's manual published by the renowned Gita Press - named [Grihastha mein kaise rahein? - Page 70 or 73 in pdf no.](https://ia801600.us.archive.org/33/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.548858/2015.548858.Grahstha-Men_text.pdf) , they recommend to endure domestic  violence.  Generally, Gita Press's publications are based on Shastras only.

Answer (score 4):

Manusmriti recommends husbands to beat their wives when they commit a fault.

> भार्या पुत्रश्च दासश्च प्रेष्यो भ्रात्रा च सौदरः ।
>   प्राप्तापराधास्ताड्याः स्यू रज्ज्वा वेणुदलेन वा ॥ २९९ ॥
>
> bhāryā putraśca dāsaśca preṣyo bhrātrā ca saudaraḥ |
>   prāptāparādhāstāḍyāḥ syū rajjvā veṇudalena vā || 299 ||
>
> **The wife**, the son, the slave, the servant and the uterine brother
>   **shall be beaten with a rope or a split bamboo, when they have
>   committed a fault**. (**Manusmriti 8.299**)

Answer (score 1):

The Agni Purana goes one step further and says that even if the wife accidentally dies while being chastised, the husband incurs no sin.

> **There is no sin when the son or pupil or wife dies when chastised.**

Source: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083402.html